# Writing a plugin system?

Tags: c++, c, linux, plugins, posix

After many hours of research I have turned up nothing, so I turn to you good folks in hopes of a solution. I am going to be writing a bot in c++, and at some point would like to make a plugin system for it. Now I know I could just write a scripting language for it, however, I know its possible to just write an api and have the program link to that dynamically at run time. My question is, how do i get that dynamic linkage (like what hexchat has for its plugins)? Are there any elegant solutions, or at least theories on the typical design?

Comment: There is no _one_ protocol for a plugin system. You would need to write a set of class factories/loader modules and loading your code from dynamic libraries at runtime, depending on your application's needs (I don't know what hexchat is and how it works with plugins). As it is, your question is too broad to answer (but still, have a look at WinAPI LoadLibrary and Linux API dlopen and consider building something around those). Voting to close.

Comment: Since you tagged C: take a look at GLibs [GModule](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html) and then [GTypeModule](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/GTypeModule.html) for a more sophisticated version with automatic interface loading.

Comment: I am not sure to have understood your question. I gave some answers.

Answer (score 7):

On Linux and Posix systems, you want to use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & `dlsym` (or some libraries wrapping these functions, e.g. [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) from GTK, [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), etc...). More precisely,

Build a [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) shared library as your plugin:

```
 gcc -fPIC -Wall -c plugin1.c -o plugin1.pic.o
 gcc -fPIC -Wall -c plugin2.c -o plugin2.pic.o
```

Notice that if the plugin is coded in C++ you'll compile it with `g++` and you should declare the plugin functions as `extern "C"` to avoid [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Then link your plugin as

```
 gcc -shared -Wall plugin1.pic.o plugin2.pic.o -o plugin.so
```

You may add dynamic libraries (e.g. a `-lreadline` at end of command above if your plugin wants GNU readline).

At last, call `dlopen` with a full path in your main program, e.g.

```
 void* dlh = dlopen("./plugin.so", RTLD_NOW);
 if (!dlh) { fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror()); 
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

(often `dlh` is a *global* data)

Then use `dlsym` to get the function pointers. So declare their signature in some header included both by program and plugin code like

```
 typedef int readerfun_t (FILE*);
```

declare some (often) global function pointers

```
 readerfun_t* readplugfun;
```

and use `dlsym` on the plugin handle `dlh`:

```
 readplugfun = (readerfun_t*) dlsym(dlh, "plugin_reader");
 if (!readplugfun) { fprintf (stderr, "dlsym failed: %s\n", dlerror());
                     exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Of course in your plugin source code (e.g. in `plugin1.cc`) you'll define

```
 extern "C" int plugin_reader (FILE*inf) { // etc...
```

You might define some constructor (or destructor) functions in your plugin (see [GCC function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)); the would be called at `dlopen` (or `dlclose`) time. In C++ you should simply use static objects. (their constructor is called at `dlopen` time, their destructor is called at `dlclose` time; hence the name of the function attributes).

At the end of your program call

```
 dlclose(dlh), dlh = NULL;
```

In practice, you can do a lot (perhaps a million) of `dlopen` calls.

You generally want to link your main program with `-rdynamic` to let its symbols be visible from plugins.

```
gcc -rdynamic prog1.o prog2.o -o yourprog -ldl
```

Read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) & [C++ dlopen mini HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/) & [Drepper's paper: *How to Write a Shared Library*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

The most important part is to define and *document* a plugin convention (i.e. "protocol"), that is a set (and API) of functions (to be `dlsym`-ed) required in your plugin and how to use them, in which order they are called, what is the memory ownership policy, etc. If you allow several similar plugins, you might have some well documented hooks in your main program which calls all the `dlsym`-ed functions of relevant `dlopen`-ed plugins. Examples: [GCC plugins conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html#Plugins), [GNU make modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Loading-Objects.html#Loading-Objects), [Gedit plugins](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit#Plugins), ...